# Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSourceRegister' unless DeleteCommand is specified

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Im getting this error when im trying to enable an delete button on my asp.net website, any solutions ??
error : Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSourceRegister' unless DeleteCommand is specified.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRegister" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegisterConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRegister" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="195px" Width="254px" DataKeyNames="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Användarnamn" HeaderText="Användarnamn" SortExpression="Användarnamn" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lösenord" HeaderText="Lösenord" SortExpression="Lösenord" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Land" HeaderText="Land" SortExpression="Land" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fullnamn" HeaderText="Fullnamn"        SortExpression="Fullnamn" />
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>

   </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I think you need add a DeleteCommand like you've added SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx